# How to write and show foreign language (Myanmar) character in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, vbe

I'm trying to put foreign language (Myanmar/Burmese) in email body.

The word turned into gibberish characters when it is sent, showing "???????".

Is there a step I'm missing or a workaround?

I tried changing the setting in VBA (i.e. Tools> Options> Editor Format> Myanmar Text(Western) and changing my laptop region setting to Myanmar also.

When I put Myanmar language characters, I expect to see

```
.HTMLBody = "Hello " &အကြီးစားလုပ်ငန်းကြီးတွေသာမက&_
```

What happened

```
.HTMLBody = "Hello " & á€¡á€€á€¼á€®á€¸á€…á€¬á€¸á€œá€¯á€•á€ºá€„á€”á€ºá€¸á€€á€¼á€®á€¸á€á€½á€±á€žá€¬á€™á€€ & _
```

Comment: Hm, find the byte code for the character and use it instead in your code (`System.Encoding.UTF8.GetString()` or something like that should be in BCL in .NET)

Comment: Store your text in an Excel cell and do `.HTMLBody = "Hello " & cell.Value`. Then you don't need to switch your laptop to anything.